# Getting error "No session Id received from SFDC". Does anything changed in Spring/Winter releases?

Tags: integration, bulk-api, session

We have integrated SAP and Salesforce system where customer data is being pushed from SAP to Salesforce. We have used Bulk API for this purpose. The issue is, the Bulk API throws the error below, which means SAP does not generate the session id. Because of that, the two interfaces are disconnected. We have followed [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_login.htm) to set up the Bulk API on SAP side an year ago.

> No session id received from SFDC

Has anything changed from Salesforce side that would break our integration like WSDL, API Version, etc?

Comment: what does CURL return you when you call it in terminal? I am able to get a response with proper token for my org

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it working locally in my system but it throws error while trying to connect from SAP.

Comment: Have you checked the logs to rule out any certificate/TLS and login IP ranges issues?

Comment: @manjit_singh we did not change anything on SAP side. It worked fine 4 months ago. For some reason, it is failing now. Trying to debug the issue. thanks